# Can pytorch be used to optimize dual problem?

Tags: optimization, pytorch

I want to use pytorch to minimize a formula,

E = Ax + b

A, x, b are 2d array with same size.

Is there any way to minimize such formula?

```
class tempModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, A, x, b):
    super().__init__()
    weights = x

    self.A = A
    self.b = b

    self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(weights), requires_grad=True)

def forward(self):
    ret = torch.matmul(self.A, self.x)
    ret += self.b

    return ret

def training_loop(model, optimizer, n=100):
    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad_(True)

    for i in range(n):
        preds = model()
        loss = loss_fn(torch.Tensor([preds]), torch.Tensor([0]))
        loss.requires_grad_(True)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.requires_grad_(False)

    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad_(False)
        return param.data
```

This is example code that I wrote, but its parameter always returns same value w

Comment: Usually, we minimize a scalar objective. Here you want to minimize `E` which looks like a matrix.  What is minimizing a matrix? That is not a well-defined concept. It is important to get the mathematical model correct (now it is somewhat nonsensical), before starting with code.

Comment: Independently from the mathematical validity of the problem, you're breaking the computation graph with `loss_fn(torch.Tensor([preds]), torch.Tensor([0]))` since you're wrapping your model prediction with `torch.Tensor`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I tried to explain my situation shortly so I had a mistake. In my real problem, forward method returns scalar value. That is, given some matrices, preds should be a scalar value and can be compared with 0. I am sorry that I wrote a strange probelm.